# defining a variable as auto restrict

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, restrict-qualifier

As I understand `restrict`, it marks a pointer as being the only reference to particular data within a function. I usually see it used in function parameters, but this is also seems to be beneficial:

```
char *restrict a = get_some_string( );
char *restrict b = get_some_other_string( );
```

(so the compiler knows that changing `a` will never change `b`, and can do extra optimisation).

If `get_some_string` returns a very complicated type, it seems best to use the `auto` keyword;

```
auto a = get_some_string( );
auto b = get_some_other_string( );
```

But using `auto restrict` triggers the error "restrict requires a pointer". So, how can I combine these?

---

As noted in the comments, `restrict` isn't a standard keyword in C++; I'd forgotten that I've got a `#define restrict __restrict__` line in my project, which works in GCC.

Comment: `decltype( get_some_string( ) ) restrict a = get_some_string( );`? Though decltype has slightly different behaviour.

Comment: Alternative suggestion:  Instead of `auto`, use a `typedef`.

Comment: @JohnDibling `typedef`s are what I used to use. But I'm trying to keep up with the times and simplify my code!

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced that seems to have the same problem; "restrict requires a pointer"

Comment: @Dave:  Personally not a big fan of `auto`, as it seems to me there is great potential for abuse and semantic obscurity.  Others will disagree.

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced I managed to get your suggestion working with `decltype(get_some_string()[0]) *restrict a = get_some_string( );`. It's a bit ugly, so I'll probably stick to `typedef`s for now! But if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Can you even do that? C doesn't have the new `auto` meaning and C++ doesn't have `restrict`.

Comment: @Angew heh, oops, I'd forgotten it wasn't standard. I added `#define restrict __restrict__` to my project, and I've got used to using it! It exists as a compiler-specific extension in several compilers.

Comment: @Dave Then you should refer to those compilers' docs, I guess. And add this bit to the question :-)

Comment: @Dave I think typedef is better here too since you are attaching a *non type* semantic meaning to the variable so making it explicit is always better. (auto is for when all your semantic meaning is embedded in the type and then it saves typing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a sort-of-solution has been suggested in the comments, I'll post it here for future reference; (with additions to make it robust)

```
typename std::remove_reference<decltype(get_some_string()[0])>::type *restrict a = get_some_string( );
```

It's horrific. I'll be sticking to `typedef`s in these cases, but I can imagine there might be situations where behaviour like this is necessary. With a macro it becomes a bit less terrible:

```
#define decltype_restrict(x) typename std::remove_reference<decltype((x)[0])>::type *restrict
decltype_restrict(get_some_string()) a = get_some_string( );
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `decltype(x[0])` instead of `decltype(*x)` or `std::remove_pointer<decltype(x)>`?

Comment: @Angew no reason. `[0]` was just the first thing which came to mind. `remove_pointer` is probably the best option.